# Cassandra time series data, limit the number of disk seeks

Tags: cassandra

I'm having trouble with excessive disk seeks for my queries.

For a query like this:

```
SELECT sessionid
FROM sessionlink
WHERE linktype = 'host'
  AND link = 'webserver1'
  AND timestamp > minTimeuuid('2016-07-02 09:00:00')
  AND timestamp < maxTimeuuid('2016-07-02 10:00:00');
```

on a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE logs.sessionlink (
    linktype text,
    link text,
    "timestamp" timeuuid,
    sessionid text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((linktype, link), "timestamp", sessionid)
);
```

I am hitting *120* SS-tables. Why is it that the query is seeking in so many SS-tables on disk, and not only the once containing data within the given dates? I've manually checked the SS-tables with `sstablemetadata` and found that only one SS-table contains the dates that are queried (looking at the minimum and maximum timestamps).

The data is inserted with:

```
INSERT INTO sessionlink(sessionid, linktype, link, timestamp)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, now()) USING TTL ?;
```

and the table is compacted with Date Tiered Compaction.

After reading the Spotify blog about Date Tiered Compaction (https://labs.spotify.com/2014/12/18/date-tiered-compaction/) and other resources I was under the impression that it would allow fast reads on time series data since the SS-tables are ordered in time and there by would minimize the number of disk reads. However, that isn't what I am seeing on my cluster.

Here is the trace of the query (with some key cache hits and seek rows removed):

```
  activity                                                                                        | timestamp                  | source        | source_elapsed
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------
                                                                               Execute CQL3 query | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.333000 | 192.168.4.184 |              0
                                             Parsing "The query from above" [SharedPool-Worker-6] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.335000 | 192.168.4.184 |             72
             READ message received from /192.168.4.184 [MessagingService-Incoming-/192.168.4.184] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.335000 | 192.168.4.186 |             23
                                                        Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-6] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.336000 | 192.168.4.184 |            236
                            Executing single-partition query on sessionlink [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.336000 | 192.168.4.186 |             80
                                           reading data from /192.168.4.186 [SharedPool-Worker-6] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.337000 | 192.168.4.184 |           1224
                                               Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.337000 | 192.168.4.186 |             85
                Sending READ message to /192.168.4.186 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/192.168.4.186] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.338000 | 192.168.4.184 |           1304
                                                Merging memtable tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.338000 | 192.168.4.186 |            371
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1168 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.339000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1003
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.339000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1007
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1167 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.339000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1029
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.343000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1031
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1278 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.343000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1965
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.343000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1968
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1277 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.344000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1982
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.344000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1984
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1276 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.344000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1996
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.345000 | 192.168.4.186 |           1999
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1275 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.345000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2011
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.345000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2013
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1274 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.346000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2026
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.346000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2027
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1273 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.346000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2040
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.346000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2041
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1272 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.347000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2053
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.347000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2078
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1271 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.347000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2090
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.348000 | 192.168.4.186 |           2092
                                                                                    ... removed some rows to make it fit ...
 REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /192.168.4.186 [MessagingService-Incoming-/192.168.4.186] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.402000 | 192.168.4.184 |          68884
                                    Processing response from /192.168.4.186 [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.403000 | 192.168.4.184 |          68953
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1188 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.403000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17630
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.403000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17632
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1187 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.403000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17647
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.404000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17649
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1186 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.404000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17665
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.404000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17666
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1185 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.404000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17884
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.405000 | 192.168.4.186 |          17886
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1184 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.405000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18098
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.405000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18100
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1183 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.405000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18314
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.406000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18317
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1182 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.406000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18537
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.406000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18540
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1181 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.406000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18754
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.407000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18756
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1180 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.407000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18971
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.407000 | 192.168.4.186 |          18974
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1179 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.408000 | 192.168.4.186 |          19212
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.408000 | 192.168.4.186 |          19215
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1178 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.408000 | 192.168.4.186 |          19434
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.408000 | 192.168.4.186 |          19437
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1177 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.409000 | 192.168.4.186 |          19656
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.409000 | 192.168.4.186 |          19658
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1176 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.409000 | 192.168.4.186 |          19873
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.409001 | 192.168.4.186 |          19875
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1175 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.410000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20093
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.410000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20096
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1174 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.410000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20309
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.410000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20311
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1173 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.410000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20537
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.411000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20539
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1172 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.411000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20762
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.411000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20765
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1171 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.412000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20985
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.412000 | 192.168.4.186 |          20987
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1170 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.412000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21212
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.412000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21214
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1169 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.413000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21230
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.413000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21232
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1166 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.413000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21497
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.414000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21501
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1165 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.414000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21928
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.414000 | 192.168.4.186 |          21930
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1164 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.414001 | 192.168.4.186 |          22476
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.415000 | 192.168.4.186 |          22479
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1163 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.415000 | 192.168.4.186 |          22494
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.415000 | 192.168.4.186 |          22496
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1162 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.415000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23103
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.415000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23107
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1161 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.416000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23124
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.416000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23126
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1160 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.416000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23753
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.417000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23757
                                             Key cache hit for sstable 1159 [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.417000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23771
                          Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.417000 | 192.168.4.186 |          23773
                                                                                 Request complete | 2016-07-08 12:06:17.402317 | 192.168.4.184 |          69317
```

Comment: Bloom Filters are not used when doing range scan. hence all the ssTables are looked upon. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_tuning_bloom_filters_c.html

Comment: I use the default `bloom_filter_fp_chance` of 0.01 (for DTC), but I'll try decreasing it.

Answer (score 0):

https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling

This is a good example on using dates in Cassandra. I believe the problem to be in how you are modelling the table. If you move your time stamp into your Partition Key Cassandra will know better on which tables to search on. If you are instead just ordering the data by (linktype, link), its going to need to search every area the data is stored in.

In short, I suggest recreating your tables with a Primary Key of **((linktype, link, "timestamp"), sessionid).**

Comment: Since "only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key", I'm unable to do any slicing queries on the timestamps with the schema you propose.

However, I've read the article and I am pretty much following the example pattern 1, except for the partitioning key being compounded. Could that have any thing to do with my problem? And should I then expect better performance if I only a single value id as the partition key? Like this `(linkid, "timestamp", sessionid)`.

Comment: Quoting the article. _A range query looking for data between two dates. This is also known as a slice since it will read a sequence of data from disk:

SELECT temperature
FROM temperature
WHERE weatherstation_id=’1234ABCD’
AND event_time > ’2013-04-03 07:01:00′
AND event_time < ’2013-04-03 07:04:00′;_ It looks like you can do a slice on date ranges, according to how I'm reading it.

Comment: In reply to your second question. I dont think you can expect any better performance with a single value partition key, you'll just be storing less data.

Comment: Yes, you can do a slicing query on dates. But not if that date is part of the *partition key*.

Comment: @SimonLindberg, thats what I was suggesting. Rewriting the partition key to include your dates.